SAPConnector: Setting BAPI Logon session failing
I'm trying to create a BAPI Logon session and setting the Audit Level, but getting an error. We are trying to use c# and SAPConnector using the sapnco libraries.
Any idea why the Bapi connection is not persisting?
func = conn.Destination.Repository.CreateFunction("BAPI_XMI_LOGON");
func.SetValue("EXTCOMPANY", "SecureCompany");
func.SetValue("EXTPRODUCT", "TestProduct1");
func.SetValue("INTERFACE", "XAL");
func.SetValue("VERSION", "1.0");

func.Invoke(conn.Destination);
string sessionname = func.GetString("SESSIONID");  //Here sessionname will have a value, so this is working.
bapiReturnData = func.GetStructure("RETURN");
//bapiReturnData.GetString("MESSAGE") is blank, so no errors.

  var func2 = conn.Destination.Repository.CreateFunction("BAPI_XMI_SET_AUDITLEVEL");
  func2.SetValue("AUDITLEVEL", "0");
  func2.Invoke(conn.Destination);
  bapiReturnData = func.GetStructure("RETURN");
  string message = bapiReturnData.GetString("MESSAGE"); 

After this code, the string 'message' will have a value of:

Not logged on generally (function BAPI_XMI_SET_AUDITLEVEL)

Since sessionname does have a value, I would expect the error not to occur. Any suggestions or help welcome.
PS: the same (or at least similar) code is working when using ERPConnect from Theobald,

Have you tried to pass the session you received on the second call? Like: func2.SetValue("SESSIONID", sessionname);

Hi. I have actually, but it gave an error as BAPI_XMI_SET_AUDITLEVEL does not have an import parameter called SESSIONID. It only has "AUDITLEVEL".

The XMI BAPIs are statefull. Therefore you need to make sure, that successive calls (e.g 1. BAPI_XMI_LOGON followed by 2. BAPI_XMI_SET_AUDITLEVEL) are running inside the same ABAP user session!
By default, the SAP .NET Connector uses connection pooling and stateless connections, which means, the effect of BAPI_XMI_LOGON is automatically cleaned up right after NCo is finished calling it... :-) (The second call might end up in a completely different user session on ABAP side, if it gets a different connection from the pool. And even if it gets the same connection as the first call, the user session has been cleaned up by NCo before using it for the first call... -- This explains, why the SET_AUDITLEVEL BAPI runs into the error "Not logged on", even though you just called LOGON BAPI right before...)
Solution: use the BeginContext() and EndContext() methods to create a stateful context! (See the NCo Programming Guide about stateful connections.)
